# python - how do I create multiple regplots together in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

assuming that I receive multiple dataframes sequentially from some tasks that I perform, how do I create regplots that will show up together - something similar to what's shown below.

[image]

```
assuming these are my codes which generate dfs with random numbers. I would like to show those 4 regplots together

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

for i in range(4):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,10),columns=['A'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,10),columns=['B'])
    df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
    sns.regplot(df1,df2)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for ax, i in zip(axs.flat, range(4)):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,10),columns=['A'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,10),columns=['B'])
    df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
    sns.regplot(x='A', y='B', data=df, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: btw I had once Q, if I had 5 graphs (instead of 4), then I change subplots (3,2), the fifth graph shows up as empty. is there anyway that empty graph is not shown?

Comment: actually found the solution - fig.delaxes(axs[2][1]) should do the trick!